# How to mask out of focus area in a photo?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I've tried to use the Laplace filter for the highest sharpness and focus detection and it works fine, but
I don't know how to use that to mask the blurred area on the original image.

[image: Laplace filter effect]

I have this piece of code so far:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

imgPath = r"IMG_0727.jpg"
img = cv2.imread(imgPath)
imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

def laplaceFilter(image):
    kernel_size = 5
    blur_size = 5
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (blur_size,blur_size), 0)
    return cv2.Laplacian(blurred, cv2.CV_64F, ksize=kernel_size)

cv2.imwrite("laplaceFilter.png", laplaceFilter(imgGray))
```

Here is what I could generate with **gaussian blur + threshold** but it's not very accurate, maybe there is a better way to do that.

[image: result1]

Comment: https://www.bogotobogo.com/python/OpenCV_Python/python_opencv3_Image_Gradient_Sobel_Laplacian_Derivatives_Edge_Detection.php 

Suggests to use kernel_size and blur_size set to 3

Comment: do you understand that out-of-focus areas can't be distinguished from uniform/featureless areas (such as the black background)? use a laplacian **pyramid**. you need to look at frequency components that are larger than your very small kernel size.

Comment: Thanks @ChristophRackwitz! Yes, I know that uniform areas are tricky and that might make this method unusable for what I need (textures projection for photogrammetry). I will take a look on laplacian pyramid approach.

Comment: You could try to close those gaps with a morphological clsoing operation, should be *quite* robust